# Why does scrlayer-notecolumn not work when I use \tableofcontents and scrwfile?

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, marginpar, scrlayer-notecolumn

I'm using the packages scrwfile (for multiple tocs after each chapter), scrlyaer-notecolumn (for putting text into the margin column) and of course \tableofcontents. But somehow this doesn't work anymore (It worked perfect a year ago, now I noticed that it doesn't anymore.) since I made a new update of my packages (29.05.2021, MiKTeX, TeXStudio, pdflatex). All notes with e.g. \makenote[marginpar] won't be printed, why? I made an example (which doesn't work):

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}%
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}%
\usepackage{scrlayer-notecolumn}%
\usepackage{scrwfile}% 1) When I load this AND use \tableofcontents, then \makenote doesn't work anymore (doesn't print anything into the margin column).

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents% 2)
Hello\makenote[marginpar]{I am here.} World.
\end{document}
```

It would be nice if anybody knows why this happens. Thanks in advance. :D

Michael Labenbacher

Edited after Ulrike's answer:
I switched to lualatex now, there I don't have any such problems, still I just want to know why I get not what I want with pdflatex.
Here an example that uses scrwfile as from the author Markus Kohm suggested (before \documentclass (and {scrlayer-notecolumn})) (same result with of course as with

```
\DeclareHookRule{enddocument/afteraux}{scrwfile}{before}{scrlayer-notecolumn}
```

):

```
\RequirePackage{scrwfile}%
\documentclass{scrreprt}%
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}%
\usepackage{scrlayer-notecolumn}%

\begin{document}%
Hello.\makenote[marginpar]{1}% Should be printed only once, but is done twice now.
\tableofcontents%
\tableofcontents%, Problem when multiple tables (doesn't matter if it's always the same or different ones like after each chapter)
\end{document}%
```

--> [image] The Result should be only one '1' in the margin column, but there are two and for every \tableofcontents there is one more.... :.( (As I said, lualatex works perfectly fine, without scrwfile and any problems, so I don't need an answer that much, just curious.)

Comment: I checked in texlive 2019 and 2018 and the double 1 is already there. So that is an old bug and not related the changes in the hooks in latex.

Answer (score 1):

If you exchange the hook code both packages use (or change the package order) it seems to work again. But you should notify the author

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}%
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}%
\usepackage{scrlayer-notecolumn}%

\usepackage{scrwfile}
\DeclareHookRule{enddocument/afteraux}{scrwfile}{before}{scrlayer-notecolumn}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents% 2)

Hello\makenote[marginpar]{I am here.} World.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer, this solution worked for me. I also posted the problem on: 
https://sourceforge.net/p/koma-script/tickets/8/
I think that's enough. I can't really find Markus Kohm's email or anything else. :D Thanks again.

Comment: I'm not a "He", I'm a woman.

Comment: Sorry ^^. But thanks again, this helped a lot, now I can compile my master thesis again. It was quite hard to find out which packages caused this since I use more than 100 at this point (e.g. glossaries-extra (bib2gls), babel, listings, scr..., hyperref, bookmark, microtype, biblatex (biber), tikz and pgf, tcolorbox, todonotes, ... just to name a few. :D)

Comment: Sorry to bother you again @Ulrike Fischer, but I made another example (added a reply to my post, because I don't know how I can format things here in the comment section), where I don't understand the behaivour and it seems the solution doesn't work that good? (Or is it just me doning something stupid ^^.)

Comment: if you have a new question, then create a new question. That is much better than to edit and extend one.